# Magento 2.2 - Mobile_detect is not working

Tags: magento2, mobile-device

```
require_once($directory->getRoot().'/Mobile_Detect.php');
$deviceDetect = new Mobile_Detect;
if ($deviceDetect->isMobile()) {
    echo "<script>alert('MOBILE');</script>";
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('WEB');</script>";
}
```

Always in all the device we get only "WEB".

Answer (score 0):

Add a function in any helper:

```
public function isMobile(){
    //return true;
    $regex_match = "/(nokia|iphone|ipad|motorola|^mot\-|softbank|foma|docomo|kddi|up\.browser|up\.link|"
        . "htc|dopod|blazer|netfront|helio|hosin|huawei|novarra|CoolPad|webos|techfaith|palmsource|"
        . "blackberry|alcatel|amoi|ktouch|nexian|samsung|^sam\-|s[cg]h|^lge|ericsson|philips|sagem|wellcom|bunjalloo|maui|"
        . "symbian|smartphone|mmp|midp|wap|phone|windows ce|iemobile|^spice|^bird|^zte\-|longcos|pantech|gionee|^sie\-|portalmmm|"
        . "jig\s browser|hiptop|^ucweb|^benq|haier|^lct|opera\s*mobi|opera\*mini|320x320|240x320|176x220"
        . ")/i";

    //DISPLAY DESKTOP THEME ON HAUWEI TAB
    if(preg_match("/(huaweimediapad)/i", strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))){
        return false;
    }

    if (preg_match($regex_match, strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android") && stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"mobile")){

        return true;

    }

    if(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android")){

        return false;

    }



    $mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
    $mobile_agents = array(
        'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
        'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
        'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
        'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
        'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
        'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
        'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
        'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
        'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

    if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    if (isset($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']) && strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini') > 0) {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

Then call this helper in your file:

```
if($this->helper('\Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->isMobile()){
 //Do mobile code
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shoaib, will check your answer and let you know.

Comment: Have you resolve your issue?

Comment: No, still not..

Comment: The same way I have called the helper class, but still not not able to achieve it..

Comment: are you calling helper in phtml or in php? calling of helper is different for both files

Comment: I am calling helper class in phtml file.

Comment: This should work them, I have personally used this code on multiple websites

Comment: I think, I am making mistakes  to call the helper class, I dont know what's the prblm..

Comment: Try to call it using object manager `$isMobile = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->create(
 \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data::class
)->isMobile();`